# anonymity set (size) for stealth address (receiver)

Tags: ring-signatures, stealth-address

S1 sends fund to R1 using a stealth addresses.

The anonymity set (size) for the receiver (R1) is the size of all possible receivers in the blockchain.

Once R1 spends the funds, the anonymity set (size) for the R1 is 11 (size of Monero ring signature).

Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

> S1 sends fund to R1 using a stealth addresses.

"stealth address" is an unfortunate moniker. When a user sends funds to another users *address*, they create new, special, *outputs* that the receiver now owns and only the receiver can spend; the receivers *address* never gets stored on the blockchain, only these newly generated outputs, which have no observable linkage to the receivers actual *address*. "stealth *outputs*" probably better describes them. Anyway, I digress...

> The anonymity set (size) for the receiver (R1) is the size of all possible receivers in the blockchain.

Yes.

> Once R1 spends the funds, the anonymity set (size) for the R1 is 11 (size of Monero ring signature).

Sort of. It's not so much the *spenders* anonymity set is 11 (the ring size), rather the true *output* being spent has an anonymity set size of 11. For each input (an output) being spent, is one of 11 possibles.

Comment: if R1 then sends the fund to R2, then for observers to trace the transactions trail, from S1 -> R1 There are 11x11 = 121 combinations. is it true?

Comment: "...from S1 -> R1 There are 11x11 = 121 combinations" - No. Each output sent from S1 to R1 is 1/11.